# Sort array of objects based on best matching another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of strings which can be seen as a template / reference:

```
// Template
let template = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
```

I also have an array of objects containing some of the array's strings:

```
// Source (to be sorted)
let source = [
   { items: ['B', 'D', 'E'] },
   { items: ['E', 'L', 'Y'] },
   { items: ['G', 'B', 'A'] },
   { items: ['C', 'B', 'A'] }
];
```

I now need to find a way to sort the `items` in the `source` array by matching to the `template` array (from best to worst). The order of the strings in the `items` is irrelevant.

Based on my example above, the result after sorting would look like this:

```
// Result after sorting
let sorted = [
   { items: ['C', 'B', 'A'] }, // 3 matches (A, B, C)
   { items: ['G', 'B', 'A'] }, // 2 matches (A, B)
   { items: ['B', 'D', 'E'] }, // 1 match (B)
   { items: ['E', 'L', 'Y'] } // no match
];
```

With the JavaScript method .sort() and .localCompare() I can sort an array based on strings but I couldn't find a way to sort by a given array 'template'.

I would be more than happy if somebody knows a way how to do that?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: source.map(a => a.items.filter(b => template.includes(b)).sort())
Here you go.

Comment: @Ankit Yeah, that won't work.

Comment: Interested to know why not @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: @Ankit have you compared the output that your solution generates with the expected output posted in the question? Clearly not.

Comment: working fine for me, make sure you don't forget to change variable name :p @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: @Ankit I'd be interested to see you post an answer with a working snippet then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239112/discussion-between-ankit-and-robby-cornelissen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can base your logic on the size of the [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) that contains distinct elements from both `template` and `items`. The smaller the `Set`, the more common items:

```js
const template = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

const source = [
   { items: ['B', 'D', 'E'] },
   { items: ['E', 'L', 'Y'] },
   { items: ['G', 'B', 'A'] },
   { items: ['C', 'B', 'A'] }
];

const target = source
  .map(({items}) => ({items, size: new Set([...items, ...template]).size}))
  .sort((a, b) => a.size - b.size);

console.log(target);
```

In case you're not dealing with distinct values in your arrays, this might be more appropriate:

```js
const template = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

const source = [
   { items: ['B', 'D', 'E'] },
   { items: ['E', 'L', 'Y'] },
   { items: ['G', 'B', 'A'] },
   { items: ['C', 'B', 'A'] }
];

const target = source
  .map(({items}) => ({
    items,
    size: items.reduce((a, v) => a + template.includes(v), 0)
  }))
  .sort((a, b) => b.size - a.size);

console.log(target);
```

This can again be further optimized by converting the `template` to a `Set`.

Comment: This has the downside of "polluting" the output data with a leftover `size` property, which isn't even the number of matches he speaks about. But maybe the OP does like that (as you don't need to recalculate it).

Comment: @Drarig29 True, but can easily filter them back out with one more `map()` or a `forEach()` and `delete`. The upside is that the calculation is only done once, compared to calculating on every element comparison in the `sort()` operation (like other answers are proposing).

Comment: I'm dealing with distinct values so your first approach is perfectly fine for me, thank you! I modified your solution in my code because my source array has more levels but I removed them in my example for simplicity reasons. Working great!

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to build a proper sorting function that compares 2 array elements. For example you can count items matching your template.

```js
function sortByMatch(template) {
  const items = new Set(template)
  
  const rank = arr => arr.filter(item => items.has(item)).length
  
  return (a, b) => rank(b.items) - rank(a.items)
}

let template = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

let source = [
   { items: ['B', 'D', 'E'] },
   { items: ['E', 'L', 'Y'] },
   { items: ['G', 'B', 'A'] },
   { items: ['C', 'B', 'A'] }
];

const sorted = source.slice().sort(sortByMatch(template))

console.log(sorted.map(item => item.items.join(', ')))
```

Comment: One major downside here: the `rank` function is executed 12 times to sort this small array, and this count will grow exponentially as the array grows.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Well, yes but "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: True enough! :)